# Можно ли употреблять слово ЛАЗАЙТЕ?

Tags: грамотная-речь, егэ

Можно ли говорить слово ЛАЗАЙТЕ?

Answer (score 1):

Да, можно. В "Новом орфоэпическом словаре русского языка" Т. Ивановой (М.,ДРОФА,2008) есть подтверждающая это статья, стр.298.

***лАзать, лАзаю, лАзает, лАзают;***

*прош.* лАзал, лАзала, лАзало, лАзали;

***пов.*** лАзай(те)

***прич.***  лАзающий, -ая, -ее, -ие; лАзавший, -ая, -ее, -ие;

***дееприч***.лАзая

Comment: А его нет в сети? Здесь без ссылок как-то не принято. Или как-то поподробнее, что ли. Ваш ответ система воспринимает как некачественный.

Comment: Хорошо, привожу статью полностью.

Answer (score 1):

А почему нельзя? Хотите быть здоровым - занимайтесь спортом, к примеру, поднимайтесь в горы, лазайте по скалам...